# JDA quzzing system using reactions: checking answers using if-then statements

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

So I have been working on JDA for a while now and I wanted to create a quiz system in which people can answer using reactions. The problem is: I am stuck on how to check who voted which reaction. I have my code here:

```
public void onMessageReactionAdd(MessageReactionAddEvent event) {
        
        MessageReaction reaction = event.getReaction();
        ReactionEmote emote = reaction.getReactionEmote();
        
        //if user reaction = certain emote then ...
}
```

I am stuck on that because I can't seem to find any API regarding a user's reaction. Any help will be appreaciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to save every single vote with the voting user in a Database.

Use [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) or [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/) for example.